# Update SharedPreferences after clicking back

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I got this code online and I am looking to make a change to it.  Basically, when I click Display Shared Preferences, then click Preferences Screen, make some changes and then click Back, the displayed preferences don't update until I click the Display Shared Preferences button again.  How do I get the preferences to be automatically updated...do I need a listener?

**PreferenceDemoTestActivity.java**

```
package Preference.Demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PreferenceDemoTestActivity extends Activity {
TextView textView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   Button btnPrefs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrefs);
   Button btnGetPrefs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetPreferences);

   textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPrefs);

   View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   switch (v.getId()) {
   case R.id.btnPrefs:
      Intent intent = new Intent(PreferenceDemoTestActivity.this,
          PrefsActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      break;

   case R.id.btnGetPreferences:
      displaySharedPreferences();
      break;

   default:
     break;
   }
   }
   };

   btnPrefs.setOnClickListener(listener);
   btnGetPrefs.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

private void displaySharedPreferences() {
   SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceDemoTestActivity.this);

   String username = prefs.getString("username", "Default NickName");
   String passw = prefs.getString("password", "Default Password");
   boolean checkBox = prefs.getBoolean("checkBox", false);
   String listPrefs = prefs.getString("listpref", "Default list prefs");

   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   builder.append("Username: " + username + "\n");
   builder.append("Password: " + passw + "\n");
   builder.append("Keep me logged in: " + String.valueOf(checkBox) + "\n");
   builder.append("List preference: " + listPrefs);

   textView.setText(builder.toString());
}
}
```

**PrefsActivity.java**

```
package Preference.Demo;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;


public class PrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
}
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
  android:id="@+id/btnPrefs"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Preferences Screen" />

<Button
  android:id="@+id/btnGetPreferences"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Display Shared Preferences" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/txtPrefs"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple update the variables with the value from `SharedPreferences` in your Activity's `onResume()` method, and then update the UI.

Your values were not changing because even though you updated them in the Preference Screen, your Activity hand simple resumed its old instance and was using the values stored in the variables.

In your case, simple calling `displaySharedPreferences()` from `onResume()` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can register for changes in the `onCreate()` method:

```
getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

and then use:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
// Update your preferences here 

}
```

Then don't forget to unregister it in `onDestroy()`:

```
getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```